# #RotationCreation

Tags: project, community

As part of the [Europa Cinemas](http://www.europa-cinemas.org/en) event that took place here in Paris this weekend, I watched a really interesting talk by David Orlic, Creative Director and Co Founder of [Volontaire](http://www.volontaire.se/en/). The discussion was based around a project they developed for the Swedish Institute and Visit Sweden entitled [Curators of Sweden](http://www.volontaire.se/en/case/curators-of-sweden/).

For those who haven't heard about it, the project saw Sweden become the first country in the world to let go of an official communication channel and hand it over to its citizens. Every week, someone in Sweden became @Sweden and therefore, the sole ruler of the country's official Twitter account. The project trended on Twitter worldwide and, after some controversial comments, gained worldwide media coverage.

Having gained worldwide media coverage, Curators of Sweden has since inspired the launch of many similar projects as well as the term Rotation Creation.

According to Wikipedia:

> Rotation Curation, also #RotationCuration, is a social media concept where official and unofficial projects, countries, cities, companies, cultural, and, or other types of groups rotate their spokespersons, curators, every week.

So, has anyone here participated in such a project with a concept of a rotating spokesperson or curator on any level? If so, how did it work out? Is there any scope to develop this idea in a sound design / recording context? We've seen various crowd sourcing projects but I'm wondering how interesting it'd be to try something like this?

Any ideas / thoughts..?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly Rotation Curation, but I did take part in a kind of chain patch thread over on the Max/msp forums which perhaps fits under Rotation Creation. Generally I like the idea of lots of people contributing to a creative project, as it then takes on a whole life of its own. If you've not seen it an awesome example of this is the [Johnny Cash Project](http://www.thejohnnycashproject.com/). Totally amazing.

So with the Max thing the idea was that everyone contributed a little bit to the patch a few objects at a time. As you might imagine it got pretty noisy! If there was interest here we could do some collaborative soundscape building or something like that, I'd be well up for it anyway. Not sure how it would work logistically though as file size is quite big. Anyone know of any online environments for this sort of collaboration?

Comment: @Mark The Johhny Cash Project is awesome! A really innovative collaboration that seems to have worked by the looks of it. It's exactly the kind of thing I'd like to participate in / develop within the context of sound, whether that be sound design or field recording. There's definitely scope to develop this somehow. Logistics seem complicated and a system / interface would need to be specifically designed. But I'm really interested to see what would happen if individuals gained complete control of the project's destiny. The "unknown" element!

Answer (score 1):

In the course of a Max/MSP class I've been taking part of this kind of collaborative work on a bigger piece, each student was writing a small part of it, that was responsible of a specific creative area, like spacialisation, filtering and so on. As @Mark said, not exactly like Rotation Curation, but you get the sense of it. But the fundamental idea are maybe more specific the problems you encounter with the rotation of curation I already experienced there: The distribution is a nice thing, but it would be much more interesting / creative if the decision of combination and artistic fingerprint would change frequently, it would carry on the idea of the collaboration.

Since Max/MSP patches are quite small compared to a DAW-session for sound-design, it shouldn't be a problem to stay with e-mail and FTP or even github (or similar) for the collaboration.

If the solution doesn't exist (I don't know of one) to work on sessions for sound design, it's time to create one. For example by using a public storage for the recorded / sampled material and a session file under version control. A subject to research further upon.

Comment: @csaudiodesign Sounds like an interesting experience. I think what worked so well with the Curators Of Sweden idea was just that. The "curator" only had one week of control, then it was handed over to someone else. This meant the project was forever evolving. 

Do you think your Max project would have been more interesting had each person had total freedom on the whole patch, but only for a specific time? Would this have helped the project develop creatively and artistically? 

Comment: @colin-hunter Absolutely it would have given the project a possibility to reach much further in a sense of representing the ideas of a group of individuals. The rotation could even include that the creative direction is handed over in fixed intervals of time. The creation and development of the parts of this big Max project could stay with individuals, but the doesn't have to. Same applies to sound design. The curators could be aiming for a common goal, i.e. to realize a certain composition or they could do whatever they wanted, it's part of the artistic development.